# Lambda query multiple strings (ruby on rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sorting

I'm trying to order my results by different string outputs.

So I have 3 different :states that that a "ticket" can be in which the user sets from a form.

- Open
- Paused
- Closed

When I want to call ticket.all i want to be able to sort it in the order stated above, so that it groups them into status type.

So how would I say first sort it by all the "Open" then by "paused" and then by "closed" all in one list?

```
  scope :statuses,  lambda { where(:status => "open", "paused",  "closed") }
```

Then Ill call ticket.statuses in my ticket controller.

I know lambda "where" query is wrong but I'm not sure how to do it any other way? How would you do an order_by on strings? Do I have to give numerical values to the :status instead?

I am using MYSQL and the gem MYSQL2

Comment: Can you say which DBMS you are using please - mysql, sqlite, pgsql etc

Comment: mysql using the mysql2 gem.

Comment: Thanks - that code should work in mysql.   it's good to put that info in the OP btw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are going to be retrieving all the tickets anyway, this would be more easily achieved by sorting in rails. For example

```
tickets = Ticket.where(:some_condition => some_value)
tickets_by_status = []
['open', 'paused', 'closed'].each do |status|
  tickets_by_status.concat tickets.select{|ticket| ticket.status == status}
end
```

Instead of abstracting this using a scope, consider creating a class method on the Ticket model, something like `all_by_status`.

[EDIT]

If you don't need the tickets to appear in the order you've specified you can simply order by status. This will sort by status alphabetically (closed, open, paused)

```
Ticket.order(:status)
```

Comment: This isn't compatible with pagination, for example, which he might want to add at some point.  It's better to do it in sql from the start if possible.

Answer (score 1):

you don't need a lambda here:  you only need to use lambda in a scope when one of the values in it may vary.  Also, i don't think this is a `where` query is it?  Am i right in thinking that you just want to order your tickets by their `status` value, and you're not setting any conditions?

If that is the case then try this:

```
scope :statuses, order("field(status, 'open', 'paused', 'closed')")
```

This is mysql-specific.  For postgres, you need to do a `CASE` statement which is a lot clunkier:

```
scope :statuses, order("CASE WHEN status='open' THEN 1 WHEN status='paused' THEN 2 WHEN status='closed' THEN 3 ELSE 4 END")
```

(i've not tested the above but i think it will work).

Comment: Are you saying that it doesn't display old data?  Or that it does?  You need to read what you're typing...  Can you give more details please.  Are you caching any data?

Comment: Sorry, its Friday and my brain is fried. The page is caching the results.If you change a status on a particular ticket then it won't show in the results until you restart the server. If I change the sort method to Ticket.order(:status) as suggested below then it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution

1.Define 3 scopes

```
scope :status_o,  lambda { where(:status => "open") }
scope :status_p,  lambda { where(:status => "paused") }
scope :status_c,  lambda { where(:status =>  "closed") }
```

2.Use it in a way

```
tickets = Ticket.status_o
tickets<<Ticket.status_p
tickets<<Ticket.status_c
```